# Express: Req.body is undefined after POST req

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I am new to node JS. 
I am getting undefined for post request. My express version is 4.10. 
I think I am missing something.

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/test',function(req,res){
    var color1 = req.body.color;   
    console.log(req.headers);
    console.log("Color : "+color1);
});
```

In content-length I am getting 234. 
[image]
Thanks!!

Comment: How are you POSTing to the server? What does the `console.log(req.headers);` show (especially the `Content-Type`)? I'm guessing it's `multipart/form-data`, which the `body-parser` module does not support.

Comment: I am using POSTMAN for posting to server.

Comment: To support multipart/form-data, which module should I suppose to use?

Comment: @mscdex Thanks!! Above code is working when I set content-type = "application/json"

Answer (score 6):

For future visitors - it seems that @mscdex's suggestion lead @Rahul to change the client calling his API so that it passed `application/json` as the value for the `Content-Type` header. Another option is to change the `Content-Type` header that `body-parser` attempts to parse.

You can configure `body-parser` to accept a different `Content-Type` by specifying the `type` it accepts as follows:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));
```

This is the solution that worked for me in order to parse the JSON sent from an Ember app. I felt it was better to change the default `Content-Type` header accepted by `body-parser` than changing the rest of the tooling around my application.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to change the default Content-Type as described above:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({
    type: 'application/vnd.api+json',
    strict: false
}));
```

`strict:false` gets around some bugs in `bodyParser` rejecting valid JSON objects.

Answer (score 0):

> npm install body-parser

However, if you are running a version of Express that is 4.16+, it now includes the same functionality inside of Express.

Instead of adding these lines in the code to get req.body:

```
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
```

If you are using Express 4.16+ you can now replace that with:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());
```